# test difference in months via PowerAutomate

Tags: list, power-automate

For a list of SharePoint items having a `BirthDate`, I need to test if between now and the date are `X` months.

I used `Get Items` query from a SharePoint list, then, for X=21

```
BirthDate eq getPastTime(21, 'Month')
```

the problem is that I need to match only the day, not the hours, and it never equals with hours and seconds.

[image]

I tried

```
// NOK, time/hours messing
BirthDate eq getPastTime(21, 'Month')

// NOK, tried to get rid of time
'@{formatDateTime(item()?['BirthDate'], 'yyyy-MM-dd')}' eq '@{getPastTime(21, 'Month', 'yyyy-MM-dd')}'
```

Comment: Try using: `BirthDate ge getPastTime(21, 'Month') and BirthDate le utcNow()`. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, as the field BirthDate in SharePoint was date only (no time), resolved with

```
BirthDate eq '@{getPastTime(21, 'Month', 'yyyy-MM-dd')}'
```